# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis'

Tags: python, import, redis, pip, easy-install

I tried to install redis-py lib via pip. It was installed successfully, but when I tried to import redis in python3 shell, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis'
```

In `python2` it gets imported with no errors.

I have tried all three pip, pip2, pip3 on my machine (ubuntu 17.10). Also I have python3.6 installed. I also tried easy_install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are installing it in Python 2.7 (you have probably already know this).  If `python3.6` brings up the correct Python version on your system then this should work for you:

```
python3.6 -m pip install redis
```

If you are unsure what each pip version brings up you can use the `which` command to list the file path.  This will give you a good indication as to where to look.

Also `pip3.6 install redis` might work but is not as secure as the above

Comment: Oddly, pip3 (which installs for python3.6) was working properly, but 'redis' wouldn't get imported. but the 'python3.6 -m pip install redis' worked.

Comment: @RezaKeshavarz  Indeed it is odd, are you sure it's not actually installing to Python 3.5 that is generally the command for 3.5.

Comment: I don't have python3.5 installed. Ubuntu 17.10 comes with python3.6 pre-installed and I didn't bother installing python3.5. But I installed Python2.7 and it's giving me a sense that there is a problem with the default python on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: @RezaKeshavarz Ah I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox so yes it's not surprising it's newer.  I would not recommend using the integrated Python, if your installation breaks so does your system.  Get one you can break if I were you (i.e install a new Python 3.6) you could also create a venv environment.